# Noindent on new type of footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indentation

Thanks to some advice I wrote the following command to avoid manually editing a footnote's number.

```
\newcounter{fncntr}
\newcommand{\fnmark}[1]{\refstepcounter{fncntr}\label{#1}\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{#1}]}
\newcommand{\fntext}[2]{\footnotetext[\getrefnumber{#1}]{#2}}
```

I am now trying to change the indent of this new footnote command to remove its by default indent.

Here is the document :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{fncntr}
\newcommand{\fnmark}[1]{\refstepcounter{fncntr}\label{#1}\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{#1}]}
\newcommand{\fntext}[2]{\footnotetext[\getrefnumber{#1}]{#2}}

\begin{document}

Here is the text\fnmark{one}

\fntext{one}{Here is the footnote.}

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: As always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal self contained document that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited my message.